# Nav bar not displaying correctly

Tags: css

Please need someone's expertise on my link; http://360webmedia.com/Store/development/index.html

In my  my menu_left.jpg is displaying correctly but my 
is not displaying my menu_right.jpg - there should be a rounded end to close off the nav bar.

This nav bar is displaying properly on another page I am working on and that page does not have the extra bootstrap.css, bootstrap-responsive.min.css and custom.css so I am not sure if one of those is affecting the nav bar. I do not know anything about bootstrap.css so am at a loss...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing "width:700px" from .menuCntr .left class and .menuCntr .right class and you can see the menu_right image. I did this using firebug and it worked for me.  Firebug is really helpful for such issues. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am really new to website design and have never used Firebug. I have downloaded it now and will read up on it and try & put it the use.  I am sure it will come in very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Change the width of `.menuCntr .right` from 700px to 630px.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. (I had 2 css.sheets and I think it was messing things up...)Your suggestion works but now I have an extra bit of menu_bg.jpg (I think) showing on the right side...can you offer any extra advice for this? Thank you.

Comment: You can try changing the width of .menuCntr to 628px.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way to change this with margins or something else that doesn't affect the stylesheet.css? Once I make this change, it affects the nav bar my on another page...